# Ajax infinity scroll and pageination error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

I'm having a problem with the ajax infinity scroll and that the back button in my browser returns me to the previous loaded part of the page. How can I make it return back to previous page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
    jQuery.ias({
        container : '.wrap', // main container where data goes to append
        item: '.item', // single items
        pagination: '.nav', // page navigation
        next: '.nav a', // next page selector
        loader: '<img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
        triggerPageThreshold: 3 // show load more if scroll more than this
    });
});
```

This is the navigation:

```
<?php if (isset($next)): ?>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href='index.php?p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now should i use Rewrite for this as it adds a new value to my url or is there another solution?

Code comes from this page: [link](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-php-mysql.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [GitHub](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/) version, then just disable *paging* and *history* plugins. If you're using the [w3bees](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-php-mysql.html) version, then in a list of defaults, you'll notice a *history* entry:

```
e.ias.defaults = {
        container: "#container",
        scrollContainer: e(window),
        item: ".item",
        pagination: "#pagination",
        next: ".next",
        noneleft: !1,
        loader: '<img src="images/loader.gif"/>',
        loaderDelay: 600,
        triggerPageThreshold: 3,
        trigger: "Load more items",
        thresholdMargin: 0,
        history: !0,
        onPageChange: function() {},
        beforePageChange: function() {},
        onLoadItems: function() {},
        onRenderComplete: function() {},
        customLoaderProc: !1,
        customTriggerProc: !1
```

Just change it's value to `history: 0;` and you'll be fine.

Comment: I tried adding history: 0; to the w3bees version, however, no changes applied. Or can't this change be added directly by editing the source code in Chrome?

Comment: If you do this in Chrome DevTools it's too late. Everything is initialized already. Try doing it on your local copy and then refresh the page.